# How to join two categories of axis text in one using ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, axis-labels, figure

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hjb59.png)

I have some figures like this one. In the x-axis I have two categories of ant behavior: subordinate and dominant.I have the effect of each ant behavior on two variables: floral visits (pink dots) and plant reproductive performance (green dots).

What I'd like to do is instead of appear subordinate and dominant twice, I'd like to appear only once and in the middle of the two variables.
Is there an easy way to do this in ggplot2?

Comment: Sure could this be achieved using for example `position_dodge`. But without any data and example code it's hard to help you any further. Hence, if you need more help provide [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) including a snippet of your data or some fake data.

Comment: Greetings! Usually it is helpful to provide a minimally reproducible dataset for questions here so people can troubleshoot your problems (rather than a table or screenshot for example). One way of doing this is by using the `dput` function on the data you are using and pasting the output into your question. You can find out how to use it here: https://youtu.be/3EID3P1oisg